# How to top align all rows in table by keeping fixed width?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am working on a LaTeX table and R, but I am facing some problems concerning column width and alignment.

```
cat("\\centering","\n")

cat("\\rowcolors{2}{burlywood1}{white}","\n")
cat("\\begin{tabular}{>{\\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}>{\\arraybackslash}m{2.25 cm}>{\\arraybackslash}m{2.25cm}c>{\\arraybackslash}m{7.5cm}c>{\\arraybackslash}m{2cm}c}","\n")
#cat("\\hline","\n")
cat("\\rowcolor{goldenpoppy} \\textbf{Col1} &\\textbf{Col2} &\\textbf{Col3} &\\textbf{Col4} &\\textbf{Col5}\\\\","\n")        
cat("\\hline","\n")
```

[image]

In the above example `Col1` is bottom aligned while others `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4` and `Col5` are top aligned. Also how can I keep column width fixed?

Comment: `m{<len>}`-columns have a fixed width of `<len>` and provides *vertically* centred alignment. That answers your question yet you're already using an `m`-column. So, perhaps you should rephrase your question...?

Comment: Ok it seems to be fixed length but why fist column is Col1 it bottomaligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m` column means centre vertically, if you want to align on the baseline of the top line in each cell use `p` not `m`.